# Use same DialogFragment to pass data back to Activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, listener

I want to be able to use the same `Dialogfragment` to pass data back an `activity` used to launch it. I also use a `fragment` to launch it. How to I implement a listener that will work with both a `fragment` and an `activity`?

Here is the code where I set up the interface in my `DialogFragment`:

```
public interface RiskListener {  
     void riskAdded(Geometry envelope, Geometry point);  
     void riskUpdated();  
}

private RiskListener listener;  

@Override  
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    listener = (RiskListener) getTargetFragment();  
}
```

I am creating the `DialogFragment` in my fragment like so:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();  
 RiskDialogFragment riskDialogFragment = RiskDialogFragment.newInstance();  
 if (!riskDialogFragment.isVisible()) {  
     riskDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(context, 0);  
     riskDialogFragment.show(fm, "RiskDialog");  
}
```

How would I set up the `DialogFragment` to work with an `Activity` as well?

Comment: post your trying code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both your Activity and Fragment should implement `RiskListener`
2. Within the activity, cast the fragment to `RiskListener`
3. Within the fragment do the following: `riskListener = (RiskListener) getActivity();` (the `onAttach()` method should be the best place to do it)

**Note:** My recommendation is to invest some time in learning some bits of MVVM and RxAndroid. It will help you solve problems like the one posted very easily and reliably. [Here](https://medium.com/@ah.shubita/android-mvvm-pattern-with-rxjava-retrofit-69fad31dcc7) is one article but you can find a lot more on the web.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I am definitely investing time in learning these principles. Would you recommend it over MVP in general?

Comment: Well, there's a lot of debate which one is better. From my personal experience MVVM allows for better testability. You should really give a chance to each of them and decide which one is better depending on your needs.Here's a short and nice article on the issue: https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/

Comment: I know some time has passed since then, but thank you for this!